# How to get Rectangle div maps in Google api v3

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

How to get 4 corner (lat & lng) when default or bounds_changed event
[image: Rectangle Point]

Answer (score 0):

This should work, put it inside a function that gets called in your bounds_changed event handler:

```
var bounds = map.getBounds();
var northEastCorner = bounds.getNorthEast();
var southWestCorner = bounds.getSouthWest();

var northWestCorner = {
    lat: northEastCorner.lat(),
    lng: southWestCorner.lng()
};

var southEastCorner = {
    lat: southWestCorner.lat(),
    lng: northEastCorner.lng()
};
```